# MediaWiki: how can I tell an extension to load load mediawiki.js and mediawiki.base.js?

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki

I'm trying to mantain an abandoned MediaWiki extension but I realized it's not that easy.

I've forked it in github https://github.com/slim16165/Semantic-MediaWiki-Graph and trying to make MW load the base javascript that defines the JS `mw.util`

**The PHP Code**

```
$wgOut->addModules(['mediawiki', 'mediawiki.base', 'mw.util']);
//$wgOut->addScriptFile("{$wgScriptPath}/resources/src/mediawiki.base/mediawiki.base.js");
 $wgOut->addScriptFile("{$wgScriptPath}/extensions/SemanticMediaWikiGraph/includes/js/d3_v4.min.js");
 $wgOut->addScriptFile("{$wgScriptPath}/extensions/SemanticMediaWikiGraph/includes/js/utility.js");
 $wgOut->addScriptFile("{$wgScriptPath}/extensions/SemanticMediaWikiGraph/includes/js/app.js");
```

**The JS Error**

```
jquery-3.6.3.js:4114 jQuery.Deferred exception: mw is not defined ReferenceError: mw is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://www.tematichedigenere.com/extensions/SemanticMediaWikiGraph/includes/js/utility.js:3:5)
    at mightThrow (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js:3830:29)
    at process (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js:3898:12) undefined
```

Testing the extension on my wiki: [link to the test page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Speciale:SemanticMediaWikiGraph?debug=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These modules are always loaded. The code is probably running too early. Ideally you'd rewrite the extension to use ResourceLoader modules and declare a dependency on `mediawiki.util`; less ideally, you can just wrap the scripts in an onload handler so they execute after everything else has.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've just understood that the way I was trying to load my script was for internal use only, now I'm trying to load them using the ResourceLoader but it doesn't work as well... I was about to open a new question asking: "In a MediaWiki extension, in a PHP file that define a class that extends SpecialPage I'm adding to the global variable $wgOut a custom module but it doesn't get loaded throught the load.php call"

Comment: I've just realized that the previous author had somehow included the js files in the module https://github.com/slim16165/Semantic-MediaWiki-Graph/blob/main/SemanticMediaWikiGraph.php isn't it enough to load them?

Comment: @Revious probably worth a separate question because it is hard to discuss in comments, but yes, the normal pattern is that you define a module and then use `$wgOut->addModule()`. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader#Registering